# Will a Haskell thread be GC'd if blocked indefinitely on an MVar/Chan/TQueue read?

Tags: multithreading, haskell

I have a thread which repeatedly takes from an `MVar`/`Chan`/`TQueue`/etc, then does some processing. Will the thread be GC'd if it has the sole remaining reference to this `MVar`/`Chan`/`TQueue`, and so is blocked indefinitely? (Does it matter whether it's an `MVar`, a `Chan`, or a `TQueue`?) And can we *rely on* this GC to happen? Under what conditions might it not happen?

If the GC doesn't happen or it's considered too fragile, what is the preferred way of shutting down a thread that is blocked on an indefinite read like this?

Comment: GHC can detect some deadlock thereby throw an exception to the thread and kill it. [The Book](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch15.html#sec_deadlock) had some discussion on when it can and when it cannot.

Comment: That makes sense. Based on reading that, it sounds like for `MVar` reads, it is guaranteed that a thread is GC-able when it is blocked indefinitely. What about `TQueue` and `Chan`?

Comment: `Chan` are nested `MVar`s, and `TQueue` works in `STM` monad which is kind of magical and can detect almost any potential deadlock in the current scope (i.e. in a single call to `atomically`). However concurrency is still one of the most error-prone topic in haskell and I recommand read [The Book](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/pt02.html) throughout before doing it in a real project.

Comment: I've got the book and will read it. I'm still looking for a simple answer to my question though for `TQueue`. For `TQueue`, say the producer thread is doing an `atomically (writeTQueue msg)`, and the consumer thread is doing an `atomically readTQueue`. If the producer gets GC'd, will the consumer, which is blocked on that `readTQueue`, be eligible for GC?

Comment: @pchiusano Any number of things could happen depending on exactly the code that's running (and optimizations, etc.). "You can’t in general know how clever the compiler is going to be, so you should not rely on deadlock detection for the correct working of your program.". When a thread is `retry`ing and hold the last reference to a `TVar` (or anything build using `TVars`, like `TQueue`) it receives a `BlockedIndefinitelyOnSTM`. So if the consumer is the holding the last reference, it *will* be interrupted - but ensuring that all other references are GCed is the really hard part.

Comment: I got it. But I would not say it is unpredictable/unreliable to reason about when references (to a `TQueue` or anything else) are reachable - it's not really any different than what you do all the time to reason about object lifetimes while programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to summarize, the answer is that a sleeping thread which is determined to have the sole reference to an `MVar` and `TVar` (which back `Chan`, `TQueue`, `TMVar`, etc), and is blocked on some use of said reference *will* be thrown an exception, which, if uncaught, will kill the thread. It really is that simple.

Caveats are that:

- You don't know when GC will run, or how aggressive it will be (perhaps the MVar has been promoted to an older generation which is collected infrequently?), so you shouldn't make assumptions about when an object becomes unreachable *in the eyes of the runtime*. Note that this is true of any runtime value that has become unreachable in a GC language, so it's not really specific to Haskell concurrency.
- It can in theory be difficult to reason about when objects are reachable, especially in the presence of optimizations. Okay, fine.

So, it's perfectly reasonable to use these runtime-triggered exceptions to shut down a thread (and reclaim its memory) that would otherwise be asleep forever, as long as you don't care about the timing of when the thread is shut down and just want some vague assurance that the thread can be shut down at some point when the runtime needs to free up some memory. This is exactly the same sort of reasoning you'd do for any values that pass out of scope in a GC language---at some point, maybe soon, maybe never, maybe an hour from now, the GC will reclaim this memory. If you need tighter control over the timing, etc, don't outsource the task to the GC.